# Not giving me directions

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I might not be understanding how this works, but if I enter in `@Model.name` which would find an address (just make one up for your testing purposes) the following javascript should find me, find the destination and find me directions.

But it doesn't. Why doesn't it? There are no console errors.

```
    function success(position) {
    var s = document.querySelector('#status');

    if (s.className == 'success') {
        // not sure why we're hitting this twice in FF, I think it's to do with a cached result coming back    
        return;
    }

    s.innerHTML = "found you!";
    s.className = 'success';

    var mapcanvas = document.createElement('div');
    mapcanvas.id = 'mapcanvas';
    mapcanvas.style.height = '400px';
    mapcanvas.style.width = '560px';

    document.querySelector('article').appendChild(mapcanvas);

    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 15,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        navigationControlOptions: { style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL },
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapcanvas"), myOptions);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map,
        title: "You are here! (at least within a " + position.coords.accuracy + " meter radius)"
    });

    var request = {
        origin: latlng,
        destination: '@Model.id',
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    };

    directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        }
    });
}

function error(msg) {
    var s = document.querySelector('#status');
    s.innerHTML = typeof msg == 'string' ? msg : "failed";
    s.className = 'fail';

    // console.log(arguments);
}

if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
} else {
    error('not supported');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must define the `map`-option for `directionsDisplay`